# Cookies getting lost after the redirect (Bottle + uWSGI + Python)

Tags: python, cookies, uwsgi, bottle

I use Bottle framework and uWSGI app server to host my website. I'm now changing the main programming language on the website (PHP->Python) and I faced the issue: cookies I've just set using `bottle.response.set_cookie()` disappeared after the redirect. So the full code is:

```
# Login page (/login)
from bottle import redirect, response # etc
...
...
response.set_cookie('cool', 'cookie') # Works good without redirect
redirect('/') # Cookie disappears
```

I knew that this problem could appear, and here it is. I hadn't this problem with PHP.
I need to set a cookie and then redirect user to the main page. Is there any way to accomplish this properly?

**UPD:**

Temporary solution for the problem is to downgrade to 0.11.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are using a version, which is affected with this bug:

https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/386

Comment: From that link: redirect() creates a new HTTPResponse and that replaces headers or cookies defined on the global response object. This is the correct behavior. I use 0.12-dev which is the latest.